# Is it possible to save data in a boost thread and retrieve it?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

Is is possible in Boost threading to do something like this:

```
std::string key;
MyClass value;    
myThread->setData(key, value);    
MyClass retrievedValue = myThread->getData(key);
```

`setData` and `getData` are only imaginary methods to explain my need.

---

**EDIT :**
I got the necessary answer by @SLaks. But for clarification : the purpose of the question was not "a method by method" equivalent, but it was a global equivalent by which **we can set somewhere in the thread by a way something that we can get it somewhere else it by a way in the same thread...** :)

Thank you!

Comment: What do theads have to do with storing key-value pairs? Use an `std::map`.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Okay, let's use a std::map, but I need this std::map to be appropriate to each thread.

Comment: Does the down-vote mean "It is not possible"? And should I accept the "Downvote" as the correct answer. HAHAHAHA

Comment: @Jessica: The downvotes are because your question is unclear and poorly phrased.  Instead of asking for two named methods, leaving us to guess what they're supposed to mean, tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SLaks, I appreciate that you explained to me what matters in my question. This helps to avoid such a mistake in my coming questions... You're awsome! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [thread-local storage](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/thread_local_storage.html).

Use `boost:thread_specific_ptr`.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I was about to lose hope...thanks to the downvotes... +1

Answer (score 1):

Not as such, no.

It is possible though, to write your own thread class (implemented in terms of std::thread or boost::thread or something else), that also holds a map of values (besides the thread instance), and that does what you are asking.

Comment: This can be a solution too, +1. But boost::thread_specific_ptr seems to me simpler.